# Error while installing AWS toolkit in STS

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to install AWS toolkit for STS on the STS version 3.9.0. I am getting following error when I am trying to install. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: AWS OpsWorks Plugin 1.0.0.v201708161930 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.opsworks.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201708161930)
Missing requirement: AWS OpsWorks Plugin 1.0.0.v201708161930 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.opsworks.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201708161930) requires 'com.amazonaws.eclipse.core 2.2.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing this issue mainly because of network connectivity issue. Due to some proxy issues with our office network, I was facing this issue.

When I tried the same at my home network, everything worked well.

Hope this would help someone.